# How to count and evaluate nodes in XML to create rowspan values in HTML table?

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xml document. And i have some nodes. 1.Management(which has some Upravlinnya), 2.Upravlinnya(which has some viddils) and that viddils (it is like department)contains some workers
And I solve my problem as you can see only with viddils. But i actually do not know why it is not working whith others.
My Table output(by now):
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSA0H.png)

And how it should be
[how should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6oKs.png)
My Xslt document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Labka -7 Kondera Sviatoslav</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Management Name</th>
        <th>Upravlinnya Name</th>
        <th>Viddil Name</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Birth Year</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Managements/Management">
        <xsl:for-each select="Upravlinnyas/Upravlinnya">
          <xsl:for-each select="Viddils/Viddil">
            <xsl:for-each select="Workers/Worker">
              <tr>
                 <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                 <td rowspan="{last()}"> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Management[1]/ManagementName"/>
                 </td>
                 </xsl:if>
                 <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                 <td rowspan="{last()}"> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Upravlinnya[1]/UpravlinnyaName"/>
                 </td>
                 </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                     <td rowspan="{last()}"> 
                     <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Viddil[1]/ViddilName"/> 
                   </td>
                 </xsl:if>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="WorkerName"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="WorkerSurname"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="BirthYear"/></td>
             </tr>    
            </xsl:for-each>  
                      
          </xsl:for-each>           
      </xsl:for-each>      
     </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also my xml document (part of my document)

```
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "labka.xsl"?>
<Managements>
  <Management id="1111">
    <ManagementName>Management_1</ManagementName>
    <Upravlinnyas>
      <Upravlinnya id="1111">
        <UpravlinnyaName>Upravlinnya_1</UpravlinnyaName>
        <Viddils>
          <Viddil id ="1111">
            <ViddilName>Viddil_1</ViddilName>
            <Workers>
              <Worker id="1111">
                <WorkerName>Sviatoslav</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>Kondera</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>2002</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
              <Worker id="2222">
                <WorkerName>Orest</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>Rodcevich</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>1999</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
              <Worker id="3333">
                <WorkerName>Olena</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>Zelenska</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>1978</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
            </Workers>
          </Viddil>
          <Viddil id ="7777">
            <ViddilName>Viddil_17</ViddilName>
            <Workers>
              <Worker id="1111">
                <WorkerName>SviatoslavNew</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>KonderaNew</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>2012</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
            </Workers>
          </Viddil>
        </Viddils>
      </Upravlinnya>
    </Upravlinnyas>
  </Management>
  <Management id="2222">
    <ManagementName>Management_2</ManagementName>
    <Upravlinnyas>
      <Upravlinnya id="2222">
        <UpravlinnyaName>Upravlinnya_2</UpravlinnyaName>
        <Viddils>
          <Viddil id ="2222">
            <ViddilName>Viddil_2</ViddilName>
            <Workers>
              <Worker id="4444">
                <WorkerName>Nidia</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>Dorofeeva</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>2016</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
              <Worker id="5555">
                <WorkerName>Petro</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>Poroshenko</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>1976</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
            </Workers>
          </Viddil>
        </Viddils>
      </Upravlinnya>
    </Upravlinnyas>
  </Management>
  <Management id="3333">
    <ManagementName>Management_333</ManagementName>
    <Upravlinnyas>
      <Upravlinnya id="3333">
        <UpravlinnyaName>Upravlinnya_222</UpravlinnyaName>
        <Viddils>
          <Viddil id ="3333">
            <ViddilName>Viddil_222</ViddilName>
            <Workers>
              <Worker id="6666">
                <WorkerName>Marsha</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>May</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>1995</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
            </Workers>
          </Viddil>
          <Viddil id ="9999">
            <ViddilName>Viddil_212</ViddilName>
            <Workers>
              <Worker id="1010">
                <WorkerName>MarshaNew</WorkerName>
                <WorkerSurname>MayNew</WorkerSurname>
                <BirthYear>1905</BirthYear>
              </Worker>
            </Workers>
          </Viddil>
        </Viddils>
      </Upravlinnya>
    </Upravlinnyas>
  </Management>
</Managements>
```

Thanks for help)
I am loooking forward your solution!)
I feel that only a few lines need to be changed

Comment: Is that image the way it should look, when all is correct; or is that the way it looks now, when something is still wrong/missing?

Comment: that the way it looks now

Comment: Can you mock up the HTML for what it should like?

Comment: I edit my question just now.And i add expected result(picture)

Comment: Your sample data only has Management_1, I don't see any Management_2 or Management_333.

Comment: now I will try to add, but there the structure is the same ( like in a box there is a box - in it one more box ...etc)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're after: you want one cell for Management_1 that spans all four rows... or more generally, you want like "keys" (Management, Upravlinnya, Viddils) grouped into single cells that span as few rows as possible.

Comment: actually yes. my supermen))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to be able, for each row you want to build, to find out if the cells should be added with a rowspan that covers their descendant rows, which you were attempting to do with:

```xml
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
```

But that test is only run in the context of Worker, so effectively your logic looks like this:

```xml
<xsl:if test="Worker first in Viddil">
  <td rowspan="{last()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Management[1]/ManagementName"/>
  </td>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="Worker first in Viddil">
  <td rowspan="{last()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Upravlinnya[1]/UpravlinnyaName"/>
  </td>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="Worker first in Viddil">
  <td rowspan="{last()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Viddil[1]/ViddilName"/>
  </td>
</xsl:if>
```

and that's why only Viddil looks correct, because the logic is correct only for Viddil; and that same Viddil-only logic is applied to Management and Upravlinnya, and it looks wrong.

In my version, I'm still testing from the context of a Worker, but I'm "reaching back **up** the tree" to the nearest ancestor that matters, and asking if that ancestor is the first.  I'm doing that with a combination of `ancestor` and `preceding-sibiling` axes:

```xml
<xsl:variable 
    name="firstUpravlinnya"
    select="count(ancestor::Upravlinnya/preceding-sibling::Upravlinnya) = 0"/>
```

All that says is, "as a Worker, find my Upravlinnya, and is my Upravlinnya the first Upravlinnya amongst all the Upravlinnyas under my Management (no siblings before/preceding it)?"

I also chose not to do this all in the nested `for-each` loops, which would work, but become difficult to read.  This uses the natural template matching characteristics of XSLT to just traverse a tree of nodes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Managements">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Management Name</th>
            <th>Upravlinnya Name</th>
            <th>Viddil Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Birth Year</th>
          </tr>

          <!-- Find all Workers, under /Managements (your "root") -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Worker"/>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <!--
    Simply match on Worker, and call row-builder to do actual work
  -->
  <xsl:template match="Worker">
    <xsl:call-template name="row-builder"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="row-builder">

    <!-- 
      From Worker, find relative positions of ancestors (if they're the first) 
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="firstUpravlinnya" select="count(ancestor::Upravlinnya/preceding-sibling::Upravlinnya) = 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstViddil" select="count(ancestor::Viddil/preceding-sibling::Viddil) = 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstWorker" select="count(preceding-sibling::Worker) = 0"/>

    <!--
      Build a row from left to right, Management to Worker.
    -->

    <tr>
      <!-- 
        One Management cell for all descendant Upravlinnyas, Viddils, & Workers
      -->
      <xsl:if test="$firstUpravlinnya and $firstViddil and $firstWorker">
        <xsl:variable name="mgmtRowSpan" select="count(ancestor::Management//Worker)"/>
        <td rowspan="{$mgmtRowSpan}">
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Management/ManagementName"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:if>

      <!-- 
        One Upravlinnya cell for all descendant Viddils & Workers
      -->
      <xsl:if test="$firstViddil and $firstWorker">
        <xsl:variable name="upravlinnyaRowSpan" select="count(ancestor::Upravlinnya//Worker)"/>
        <td rowspan="{$upravlinnyaRowSpan}">
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Upravlinnya/UpravlinnyaName"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:if>

      <!-- 
        One Viddil cell for all descendant Workers
      -->
      <xsl:if test="$firstWorker">
        <xsl:variable name="viddilRowSpan" select="count(ancestor::Viddil//Worker)"/>
        <td rowspan="{$viddilRowSpan}">
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Viddil/ViddilName"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:if>

      <!-- Always add cells for a Worker -->
      <td><xsl:value-of select="WorkerName"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="WorkerSurname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="BirthYear"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone!!!That two solution is solved my issue.But i can not choose 2 answers as correct.(I do not know why).

Comment: @Sviatoslavch, just the way StackOverflow is. But you can still up-vote Michael's answer (... and mine, too ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Managements">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Management Name</th>
                    <th>Upravlinnya Name</th>
                    <th>Viddil Name</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Birth Year</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Management"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Management">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{count(Upravlinnyas/Upravlinnya) + count(Upravlinnyas/Upravlinnya/Viddils/Viddil) + count(Upravlinnyas/Upravlinnya/Viddils/Viddil/Workers/Worker) + 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="ManagementName"/>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Upravlinnyas/Upravlinnya"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Upravlinnya">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{count(Viddils/Viddil) + count(Viddils/Viddil/Workers/Worker) + 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="UpravlinnyaName"/>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Viddils/Viddil"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Viddil">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{count(Workers/Worker) + 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="ViddilName"/>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Workers/Worker"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Worker">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="WorkerName"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="WorkerSurname"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="BirthYear"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>         

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Management Name</th>
            <th>Upravlinnya Name</th>
            <th>Viddil Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Birth Year</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="8">Management_1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="7">Upravlinnya_1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Viddil_1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Sviatoslav</td>
            <td>Kondera</td>
            <td>2002</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Orest</td>
            <td>Rodcevich</td>
            <td>1999</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Olena</td>
            <td>Zelenska</td>
            <td>1978</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Viddil_17</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SviatoslavNew</td>
            <td>KonderaNew</td>
            <td>2012</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">Management_2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Upravlinnya_2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Viddil_2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Nidia</td>
            <td>Dorofeeva</td>
            <td>2016</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Petro</td>
            <td>Poroshenko</td>
            <td>1976</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="6">Management_333</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">Upravlinnya_222</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Viddil_222</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Marsha</td>
            <td>May</td>
            <td>1995</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Viddil_212</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>MarshaNew</td>
            <td>MayNew</td>
            <td>1905</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered**

[image]

---

Note that this is not a strictly correct solution. Ideally, the first row of every section should contain a cell for every column in the table, and likewise, the first row of each subsection should contain a cell for each of the columns remaining to the right-hand side of the subsection's column.

Because of this, the result is very slightly skewed: the top borders of the cells in the same row do not align perfectly. However, I believe it's a small price to pay for such simplicity of code.

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't know rowspan worked like that. Thanks for showing how to use that nature to build the structure from the top-down! :)

Comment: @ZachYoung Actually, it's somewhat of a hack; I've added a note explaining this.

Comment: Thanks everyone!!!That two solution is solved my issue.But i can not choose 2 answers as correct.(I do not know why)